# When to use non-template function and template specialization function

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to understand template specialization . The below code prints "base 1 bas2". If I uncomment line (a), ie, to make is_odd (bool) as template specialization for bool, still I get same output. My question is when should I use non-template function/function template specialization?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct util {
public:
    template <class T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,bool>::type
    is_odd (T i);

    template <class T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value,bool>::type
    is_odd (T i);

    //bool is_odd (bool);

    template <class T>
    T is_oddImpl (T i);
};

template <class T>
T util::is_oddImpl (T i) {
    return is_odd(i);
}

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,bool>::type
util::is_odd (T i) {std::cout << "base1\n"; T t; return t;}

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value,bool>::type
util::is_odd (T i) {std::cout << "base1\n"; T t; return t;}

//template <>  //line (a)
bool util::is_odd (bool) {std::cout << "base3\n";return true;}

int main() {
    short int i = 1;
    bool b;
    ss test;

    struct util s;

    s.is_oddImpl(i);
    s.is_oddImpl(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @W.F. if I uncomment line "//template <>  //(a)", then the code will contains template specialization i think... so I want to know when to use template specialization over function overloading...

Comment: oh sorry I haven't seen it...

Comment: What's the compiler and version? I can't reproduce with Clang. http://rextester.com/ACO94798

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7780159ea1d8df44

Comment: I not sure what you're trying to accomplish with SFINAE here.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod My question is if I make "is_odd (bool)" as specialized function(by uncommenting line (a)), will there be any change in functionality?

Comment: No change in functionality between the two. You should generally use overloading where you can and template specialization only where necessary.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasMcLeod